# Auto-create google docs file when uploading photo to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, ocr, google-docs

I have a bunch of screenshots (probably in thousands) that I want to run OCR on. I tried different services but Google Drive results are far better. But the process is a little tedious. First I have to upload a photo to Google Drive and then right click the uploaded file and select "Open with -> Google Docs". The resultant doc file contains all the text that was in the screenshot. However, it works for only one file at a time.

So is there a way to tell Google Drive to automatically create the doc file for every photo at the time I upload them.

I know there is Google Drive API that could help in this regard but I have very limited experience with coding and API. I could use a program if available.

Comment: Looks like this script by Tanaike is what you're looking for https://tanaikech.github.io/2017/05/02/ocr-using-google-drive-api/

Comment: Thanks a bunch. The script worked as I needed and returned a .txt file with the text. But can you assist me further on how to run this script on a folder with a few sub-folders while also keeping the folder hierarchy. Thanks again.

Comment: I think maybe you should ask a new question for this documenting what you have tried :)